# Configuring Highlightjs with primeng p-editor

Tags: angular5, syntax-highlighting, primeng, highlightjs

I am using primeng version - 5.2.4 with angular 5.2.9

I using primeng p-editor for editing some sql scripts. I know p-editor uses quill internally and quill supports syntax highlighting using highlightjs. I would like to know how configure highlightjs with primeng p-editor in angular 5.

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by replacing primeng p-editor with ngx-quill plugin [here](https://github.com/KillerCodeMonkey/ngx-quill)

The primeng p-editor uses an older version of quill.